# How to append at end of file for shell in C?

Tags: c, shell, append, output

I am trying to write the shell program in C for I/O redirection. The input and output is working fine, but I also have to append output to the end of a file with the '>>', but it's not working. Whenever, I use >> in the command line, it just overwrites the output to the file. And I also get a warning when I run the program: warning: multi-character character constant. I would really appreciate it if someone can please assist me in the right direction to fix this problem.

```
        // Check for redirected input
        input = redirect_input(args, &input_filename);

        switch(input) {
        case -1:
          printf("Syntax error!\n");
          continue;
          break;
        case 0:
          break;
        case 1:
          printf("Redirecting input from: %s\n", input_filename);
          break;
        }

        // Check for redirected output
        output = redirect_output(args, &output_filename);

        switch(output) {
        case -1:
          printf("Syntax error!\n");
          continue;
          break;
        case 0:
          break;
        case 1:
          printf("Redirecting output to: %s\n", output_filename);
          break;
        }

        // Check for redirected append output
        append = redirect_append(args, &append_filename);

        switch(append) {
        case -1:
          printf("Syntax error!\n");
          continue;
          break;
        case 0:
          break;
        case 1:
          printf("Redirecting output to: %s\n", output_filename);
          break;
        }



        // Do the command
        do_command(args, block, 
               input, input_filename, 
               output, output_filename,
               append, append_filename);
      }
    }


    /* 
     * Do the command
     */
    int do_command(char **args, int block,
               int input, char *input_filename,
               int output, char *output_filename,
               int append, char *append_filename) {

      int result;
      pid_t child_id;
      int status;

      // Fork the child process
      child_id = fork();

      // Check for errors in fork()
      switch(child_id) {
      case EAGAIN:
        perror("Error EAGAIN: ");
        return;
      case ENOMEM:
        perror("Error ENOMEM: ");
        return;
      }

      if(child_id == 0) {

        // Set up redirection in the child process
        if(input)
          freopen(input_filename, "r", stdin);

        if(output)
          freopen(output_filename, "w+", stdout);

        if (append)
          freopen(append_filename, "a", stdout);

        // Execute the command
        result = execvp(args[0], args);

        exit(-1);
      }

      // Wait for the child process to complete, if necessary
      if(block) {
        printf("Waiting for child, pid = %d\n", child_id);
        result = waitpid(child_id, &status, 0);
      }
    }

    /*
     * Check for input redirection
     */
    int redirect_input(char **args, char **input_filename) {
      int i;
      int j;

      for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++) {

        // Look for the <
        if(args[i][0] == '<') {
          //free(args[i]);

          // Read the filename
          if(args[i+1] != NULL) {
        *input_filename = args[i+1];
          } else {
        return -1;
          }

          // Adjust the rest of the arguments in the array
          for(j = i; args[j-1] != NULL; j++) {
        args[j] = args[j+2];
          }

          return 1;
        }
      }

      return 0;
    }

    /*
     * Check for output redirection
     */
    int redirect_output(char **args, char **output_filename) {
      int i;
      int j;

      for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++) {

        // Look for the >
        if(args[i][0] == '>') {
          //free(args[i]);

          // Get the filename 
          if(args[i+1] != NULL) {
        *output_filename = args[i+1];
          } else {
        return -1;
          }

          // Adjust the rest of the arguments in the array
          for(j = i; args[j-1] != NULL; j++) {
        args[j] = args[j+2];
          }

          return 1;
        }
      }

      return 0;
    }

    /*
     * Check for append redirection
     */
    int redirect_append(char **args, char **append_filename) {
      int i;
      int j;

      for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++) {

        // Look for the >>
        if(args[i][0] == '>' && args[i][1] == '>') {
          //free(args[i]);

          // Read the filename
          if(args[i+2] != NULL) {
        *append_filename = args[i+2];
          } else {
        return -1;
          }

          // Adjust the rest of the arguments in the array
          for(j = i; args[j-1] != NULL; j++) {
        args[j] = args[j+2];
          }

          return 1;
        }
      }

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Fixing the warning should be easy, at least you know where it is. Maybe you can tell us?

Comment: TL;DR. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
if(args[i][0] == '>>') {
```

Should be:

```
if(args[i][0] == '>' && args[i][1] == '>') {
```

This is the source of your "multi-character constant" warning as well as your output redirection problem.

Comment: It removed the warning, but the >> still overwrites whatever was in the output file.

Comment: Your '>' logic is conflicting with your '>>' logic. You should probably handle these together.

Comment: I am confused in how to achieve that logic.

Comment: In `do_command` you could do something like `if (append) { freopen(append_filename, "a", stdout); } else if(output) { freopen(output_filename, "w+", stdout); }`. Your `redirect_append` has other issues -- `if(args[i+2] != NULL) { *append_filename = args[i+2]; }` should be `if(args[i+1] != NULL) { *append_filename = args[i+1]; }` I think.

Comment: Oh the args[i+2] was typo. But I tried the if-else if way, it's still overwriting the file instead of appending.

Comment: Looks like it's time to break out the debugger.